# For discs around $n$ points in $\mathbb R^2$, what is the maximum number of overlapping regions without all discs overlapping?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given some points in the plane with closed discs of fixed radius centered at each point, what is the maximum number of overlapping regions that can exist, without all discs overlapping?

More precisely, let $X\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be a set of $n$ points, and fix $r\geq 0$. For each $n$, let $D_n$ be the closed disc of radius $r$ centered at $n$. Let $C$ be the number of distinct regions in which two or more discs overlap.

What is the maximum size of $C$ as a function of $n$, with the restriction that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n D_i = \emptyset$?

In particular, I would like to know if $C$ can have size $O(n^2)$. I suspect not, but that is just from drawing many examples. I know, of course, that $C$ is at least of size $O(n)$, but I couldn't do better than that.

To get an intuition for what I am asking, in the below example (not perfectly drawn), $n=4$ and $C=6$.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the problem was being bad at recreating the maximum case instead of being bad at counting. Note that if you move the top right circle inwards you get 7 regions without  violating the not-all-overlap rule. (But I think you can get 8.)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't trying to recreate any particular case, I was just making a drawing to explain what I am talking about.